# Uniform convergence of fourier series of step function

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

Consider the series 
$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \sin nx$,
where 
\begin{align}
a_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{4}{n \pi}, &n \text{ odd} \\
0, &n \text{ even}
\end{cases}.
\end{align}
It is easily seen that 
\begin{align}
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
-1, & - \pi < x < 0 \\
0, & x= 0 \\
1, & 0 < x < \pi
\end{cases}.
\end{align}

Does this series converge uniformly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because a series of continuous functions cannot converge uniformly to a discontinuous function.